# in android nothing displayed

Tags: android

I am doing a application that has database coding and some classes. I put Log.e() after and before the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in main activity but no log value printed in Logcat and no design applied for the main activity.

my logcat prints:

> 05-03 16:19:06.011:
>   ERROR/PackageInstallationReceiver(289):
>   Remove
>   /data/local/tmp/com.sai.thread.apk
>   Fail! 05-03 16:19:31.451:
>   ERROR/SETTING_AUTO_BACKLIGHT(59):
>   open:
>   /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/auto
>   failed, errno: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U may need to remove the application from device or emulator other wise delete the table rows from table by using

String sqlDeleteData="delete from "+TABLENAME+";";
SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlDeleteData);

Answer (score 0):

Your application could not be reinstalled on the device / emulator, try to delete it first manually via Preferences >> Applications >> Manage Applications.

Comment: i have htc device i uninstall the application via 'menu->setting->application->manage application->sdkexample->uninstall' and re run the application i got the same error. please help me.